# Simplifying this else if conditional into a loop (without throwing errors)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

Here we go! I'm creating a drag and drop game (simple enough) that only identifies wrong pieces after a submit button is hit. I originally believed this could be done using arrays and a for loop that checked them, but every time i did that, it never stored the data into the dragged clips, so they all displayed "wrong". Since then I have created a lengthy conditional else if, that honestly feels clunky,but works perfectly fine. Any thoughts?

```
import flash.filters.*
import flash.display.Sprite;


var dragArray:Array = [it_1, it_2, it_3, it_4, it_5, it_6, it_7, it_8, it_9];
var matchArray:Array = [mat_1, mat_2, mat_3, mat_4, mat_5, mat_6, mat_7, mat_8, mat_9];
var currentClip:MovieClip;
var startX:Number;
var startY:Number;
var wrongGlow:GlowFilter= new GlowFilter();
wrongGlow.alpha=1;
wrongGlow.color = 0xFF0000;
wrongGlow.blurX = 20;
wrongGlow.blurY = 20;


submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, objCheck);


function objCheck(event:MouseEvent):void {
//  var index:int = dragArray.indexOf(dragArray);
//  var matchClip:MovieClip = MovieClip(matchArray[index]);

for(var c:int=0; c < dragArray.length; c++){
    if(dragArray[c].Boolean == false){
//         dragArray[c].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    dragArray[c].buttonMode = false;
    dragArray[c].filters = [];
}else{
dragArray[c].filters = [wrongGlow];
}
}

}

for(var i:int = 0; i < dragArray.length; i++) {
dragArray[i].buttonMode = true;
dragArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
}

function item_onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
currentClip = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);
addChild(currentClip);
currentClip.startDrag();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp);

}



function stage_onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
//  stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp);
currentClip.stopDrag();
var index:int = dragArray.indexOf(dragArray);
var matchClip:MovieClip = MovieClip(matchArray[index]);
/*  if(currentClip.hitTestObject(matchClip)){
    currentClip.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    currentClip.Boolean= false;
}else{
    currentClip.Boolean=true;
}
}*/

if (currentClip == it_1){
 if (it_1.hitTestObject(mat_1)){
    it_1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_1.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_1.Boolean= true;
 }
} else if (currentClip == it_2){
 if (currentClip.hitTestObject(mat_2)){
    it_2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_2.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_2.Boolean= true;
 }
} else if (currentClip == it_3){
 if (currentClip.hitTestObject(mat_3)){
    it_3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_3.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_3.Boolean= true;
 }
} else if (currentClip == it_4){
 if (currentClip.hitTestObject(mat_4)){
    it_4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_4.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_4.Boolean= true;
 }
} else if (currentClip == it_5){
 if (currentClip.hitTestObject(mat_5)){
    it_5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_5.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_5.Boolean= true;
 }
} else if (currentClip == it_6){
 if (currentClip.hitTestObject(mat_6)){
    it_6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_6.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_6.Boolean= true;
 }
} else if (currentClip == it_7){
 if (currentClip.hitTestObject(mat_7)){
    it_7.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_7.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_7.Boolean= true;
 }
} else if (currentClip == it_8){
 if (currentClip.hitTestObject(mat_8)){
    it_8.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_8.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_8.Boolean= true;
 }
} else if (currentClip == it_9){
 if (currentClip.hitTestObject(mat_9)){
    it_9.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    it_9.Boolean= false; 
 }else{
     it_9.Boolean= true;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably shorten it into a for loop like this:

```
for (var i:int=0; i < dragArray.length; i++){
    if (currentClip == dragArray[i]){
        if (currentClip.hitTestObject(matchArray[i])) {
            dragArray[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
            dragArray[i].Boolean = false; 
        } else {
            dragArray[i].Boolean = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a loop like that, but it wouldn't save the Boolean value to the mc's after they were active. So eventually it would just say in the end that all of their Booleans were true.

Comment: That's weird.. My guess is that when you define the arrays, it's actually creating and adding copies of `it_1, it_2, ...` instead of storing a reference to the same object. I'll look into it and see if there is a way to make sure the arrays store references to the objects instead of copies. Everything I've seen so far, however, states that it should actually be references..

Comment: Yeah, I found it weird too, but then i just looked at onMouseDown and realized it makes a child of each of the mcs...maybe thats it. I wonder how to get around that.

Comment: Perhaps create another function that has access to the global arrays? Something like `function setBoolean(index:int, value:boolean):void { dragArray[index].Boolean = value; }` and call that from inside the loop instead of trying to set the Booleans directly.